# App made in android studio doesn't work in phone

Tags: android

We created a game in android studio. It runs on Blue stack and on my friend's phone perfectly but on my phone the splash screen is shown (without the background image..while on Blue stack and on my friend's phone the image is shown) and when I press the enter button instead of going to the level selection window, the "Unfortunately, app has stopped..." message is displayed. What could be the problem? Please help!! My phone is Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505.

### EDIT LogCat

```
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glUniformMatrix3x4fv" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glUniformMatrix3x4fv missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glUniformMatrix4x2fv" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glUniformMatrix4x2fv missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glUniformMatrix4x3fv" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glUniformMatrix4x3fv missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glUnmapBuffer" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ found <glUnmapBufferOES> instead
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glUseProgramStagesEXT" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glUseProgramStagesEXT missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glValidateProgramPipelineEXT" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glValidateProgramPipelineEXT missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glVertexAttribDivisor" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glVertexAttribDivisor missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glVertexAttribI4i" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glVertexAttribI4i missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glVertexAttribI4iv" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glVertexAttribI4iv missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glVertexAttribI4ui" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glVertexAttribI4ui missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glVertexAttribI4uiv" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glVertexAttribI4uiv missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glVertexAttribIPointer" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glVertexAttribIPointer missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? W/PGA﹕ eglGetProcAddress: "glWaitSync" not found
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/libEGL﹕ glWaitSync missing: using gl_unimplemented
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 285K, 24% free 2848K/3732K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 0ms
08-30 13:42:46.177  14078-14078/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 194K, 29% free 2653K/3732K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 0ms
08-30 13:42:46.187  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.187  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t filter -A OUTPUT -j st_filter_OUTPUT
08-30 13:42:46.197  14078-14078/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 29% free 2653K/3732K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 20ms
08-30 13:42:46.197  14078-14078/? I/Zygote﹕ Accepting command socket connections
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `raw': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t raw -N bw_raw_PREROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `raw': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -N bw_raw_PREROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `raw': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j bw_raw_PREROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `raw': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.207  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j bw_raw_PREROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `raw': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t raw -N idletimer_raw_PREROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `raw': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -N idletimer_raw_PREROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `raw': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j idletimer_raw_PREROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `raw': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.217  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j idletimer_raw_PREROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.257  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.257  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.257  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.257  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -N bw_mangle_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.267  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.267  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.267  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.267  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j bw_mangle_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.307  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.307  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.307  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.307  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -N idletimer_mangle_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.317  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.317  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.317  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.317  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j idletimer_mangle_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.357  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.357  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.357  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.357  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -N st_mangle_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.367  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.367  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.367  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.367  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j st_mangle_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.407  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.407  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.407  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.407  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -N st_mangle_EXEMPT
08-30 13:42:46.417  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.417  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.417  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.417  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j st_mangle_EXEMPT
08-30 13:42:46.457  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.457  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.457  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.457  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -N st_mangle_OUTPUT
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j st_mangle_OUTPUT
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -N oem_nat_pre
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.467  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j oem_nat_pre
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -N natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -N st_nat_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j st_nat_POSTROUTING
08-30 13:42:46.487  14077-14077/? V/NatController﹕ runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -F natctrl_FORWARD) res=3
08-30 13:42:46.517  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.517  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.517  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.517  14077-14077/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=768 failed /system/bin/iptables -N bw_happy_box
08-30 13:42:46.527  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.527  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.527  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.527  14077-14077/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=768 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -N bw_happy_box
08-30 13:42:46.547  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.547  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.547  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.547  14077-14077/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=768 failed /system/bin/iptables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
08-30 13:42:46.547  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.547  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.547  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.547  14077-14077/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=768 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
08-30 13:42:46.557  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.557  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.557  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.557  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -F st_mangle_OUTPUT
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -F st_mangle_EXEMPT
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? I/iptables﹕ iptables terminated by exit(1)
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=256 for /system/bin/iptables -t mangle -A st_mangle_OUTPUT -m mark --mark 1 -j RETURN
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.567  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -A st_mangle_OUTPUT -m mark --mark 1 -j RETURN
08-30 13:42:46.577  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
08-30 13:42:46.577  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
08-30 13:42:46.577  14077-14077/? I/ip6tables﹕ ip6tables terminated by exit(3)
08-30 13:42:46.577  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t mangle -A st_mangle_OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner vpn -j RETURN
08-30 13:42:46.577  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported
08-30 13:42:46.577  14077-14077/? E/Netd﹕ Unable to open quota2 logging socket
08-30 13:42:46.577  14077-14077/? D/MDnsDS﹕ MDnsSdListener::Hander starting up
08-30 13:42:46.577  14077-15195/? D/MDnsDS﹕ MDnsSdListener starting to monitor
08-30 13:42:46.577  14077-15195/? D/MDnsDS﹕ Going to poll with pollCount 1
```

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Skizo. You're awesome! :P